# Multiple Display In One-Page Tableau Dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

I am a new Tableau user. I have a concept to create one-page dashboard as summary page which contains two main windows. First window is fixed, displaying general information by pie chart. Second window (below) is dynamic, displaying detailed information of clicked pie chart. Every pie chart has different format/ layout of detailed information. Could I visualize the concept using Tableau. Please enlighten me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes you can.** This is Tableau's bread and butter. Click an item in the dashboard and everything else can be filtered to that item. Look at `Dashboard Actions` to accomplish this.

[image]